# Two harddrives fails in just one year

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

Last year one of my hard drives failed (it was quite old, more than 3 years of extensive usage), so I replaced that one with another one, but now that one also has failed.

Is it just an coincidence or a hardware failure on the mobo?

Symptoms before the first failure:

- Hard drive started giving clicking sounds
- Hard drive sometimes not recognized

---

Edit: Ubuntu gives me this error: EMask 0x50 ATA Bus Error

Current symptoms:

- Hard drive started giving clicking sounds
- Since I now use BTRFS with raid 1 my system keeps starting up but the raid drive sometimes disappears
- Issues rised quite soon (after 6 months of usage)
- Worked without issues for the last 2 or 3 months
- Now giving more issues

What I have tried so far:

- Changed SATA port
- Changed power cable

**System Info**:

- OS: Ubuntu Linux (22.04 server)
- FS: BTRFS
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus B550

Answer (score 0):

Hard drive failures follow the bathtub curve. Manufacturing imperfections cause some drives to die early and survivors live until their natural death. That means the early failure of your drive could have simply been bad luck. It should be covered by the warranty.

Clicking may or may not be normal. Some drives click during normal operation. If the drive clicked since it was new, I would assume it's normal for that model. Anyway, clicking wouldn't be caused by external factors.

Drive sometimes not being recognized by the system suggests possibility of power cable not making a good connection. Check for signs of sparking or loose connectors.

Comment: Well, brands of the HDDs are also important - some fail earlier, some after many years.

Comment: What is the environment? Well-filtered indoor air, or exposed to hazards such as damp, dusty or salty air?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it is quite well filtered. The is an laptop with a magnetic strip on top of the case in which the harddrives reside